# Is "the meaning of these signs" a singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of these sentences is correct?

"The meaning of these signs are well-understood."

"The meaning of these signs is well-understood."

Answer (score 2):

The 'meaning' is the subject of the sentence. It needs a verb in singular. So 'the meaning... is ...'

Answer (score 2):

If the signs all have the same meaning, then "The meaning of these signs is well-understood." makes sense, since *meaning* is singular.

If however you are talking about different meanings in a collection of signs, you should use: "The **meanings** of these signs **are** well-understood."